# What's the difference between these two definitions?

Tags: perl, perl-hash

Why it's a syntax error:

```
my @hash{1..4}=(1..4);
```

but not this one:

```
my %hash;
@hash{1..4}=(1..4);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the 1st example is of a lexically scoped ['my'](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) + a [hash slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) which pre-supposes that one can declare a hash in the manner of a slice which is not valid syntax. your 2nd example is appropriate, declaring the hash first, assuming that you're use'ing strict + warnings;

Comment: This is a syntax error question, not a "variables must be declared (must exist) to be used" question.  You can slice-assign to a hash that didn't previously exist:  `perl -E '%h{1..4}=(); say for keys %h;'`.  The OP's problem is that you can't `my` declare *and* access elements in the same statement.

Comment: correct, which i thought was implicit in what i said. perhaps not, hence why i linked to the perldata slice page.

Comment: The way you've phrased your answer make it seem (to me) that you are identifying the non-existence of `%hash` as the issue, rather than the syntactically botched declaration as the issue.

Comment: :shrug: other folks seem to have understood and my answer was accepted so it appears what i said was sufficient for the OP. but i can see where my quick explanation didn't completely lay out the semantic differences between syntax, data structure, and slice.

Comment: @ikegami i've redone my post. i look forward to more polite, friendly, and constructive comments from you in the future.

Comment: Comments and -1 retracted as they no longer apply.

Answer (score 5):

`my` requires a variable or a list of variable in parens as argument.

```
@hash{1..4}
```

is neither of those, so

```
my @hash{1..4}
```

is a syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

First example fails, because hash slice is an operation that returns some result. Obviously, perpending it with `my` declaration makes no sense, just like writing something like `my 2+2` wouldn't. [`my` must be followed by list of variables to declare](http://p3rl.org/my).

Second example does just that - declares a hash in current scope and then accesses a slice of it.

Comment: `$a` is also an operation that returns some result, yet you can place a `my` in front of it. This is not a correct answer, although it's close.

Comment: "my must be followed by list of variables to declare" should cover what exactly `my` is valid with.

Comment: It's the first sentence I commented on. (Although that one is not quite right either: `my $x, $y` doesn't do what you said it does.)

Comment: Well, I'll just add a link to `my`, so I don't have to quote it entirely.